# Are there reasons why Nokogiri would not parse all of the HTML on a certain page? (with example)

Tags: ruby

For practice, I am trying to build a simple scraper for the rates in each respective hostel card on this page:

https://www.hostelworld.com/search?search_keywords=Madrid,%20Spain&country=Spain&city=Madrid&date_from=2019-11-29&date_to=2019-11-30&number_of_guests=1

When I inspect the page, the HTML clearly shows that each price is within a span with the class "price" ('span.price'). So, I am getting the page body with Mechanize and then trying to parse the body with Nokogiri.

Using this simple example, I can't seem to access any information in the cards. Code below:

```
def scraper
  agent = Mechanize.new
  madrid_url = "https://www.hostelworld.com/search? 
  search_keywords=Madrid,%20Spain&country=Spain&city=Madrid&date_from=2019-11- 
  29&date_to=2019-11-30&number_of_guests=1"
  ###
  page = agent.get(madrid_url)
  page_body = agent.page.body
  parsed_body = Nokogiri::HTML(page_body)
  ###
  test = parsed_body.css('span.price').text
  test_price = test.to_i
  byebug
end
```

Any tips would be appreciated! It just seems counter-intuitive that I can see the HTML/CSS, but cannot access it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, lots of websites load data via AJAX (XHR) requests. This data would not be available to Mechanize.

You can easily check this by loading the page with JavaScript disabled in your browser. If prices are not displayed, it means they got lazy loaded by JavaScript.

In this case, you would need a tool which can execute JavaScript, e.g. [Selenium](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: Ah, thank you. This makes sense. So, I need to use the "selenium-webdriver" (https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver) gem to execute the JS and then I will be able to use Nokogiri to parse the loaded data?